# How to convert Node crypto.generateKeyPairSync to Deno?

Tags: javascript, deno, webcrypto-api

I want to convert the following code from a Node (v18.1) program to Deno (v1.22), where a key pair is generated during SSH key exchange:

```
// generate.mjs
import { generateKeyPairSync } from "crypto";

const keys = generateKeyPairSync("x25519");
```

The code above is part of a larger SSH client, which mostly works in Deno when run in Node compatibility mode (`--compat`). However, `generateKeyPairSync` is [not yet implemented](https://github.com/denoland/deno_std/blob/main/node/internal/crypto/keygen.ts#L662), so I want to change it to a Deno equivalent:

```
deno run --compat --unstable --allow-env ./generate.mjs

error: Uncaught Error: Not implemented: crypto.generateKeyPairSync
  throw new Error(message);
        ^
    at notImplemented (https://deno.land/std@0.142.0/node/_utils.ts:22:9)
    at generateKeyPairSync (https://deno.land/std@0.142.0/node/internal/crypto/keygen.ts:662:3)
    at file:///C:/Users/gjzwiers/repos/nodeno_ssh/generate.mjs:3:14
```

I have looked at [`generateKey` in the WebCrypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/generateKey), but it seems that it does not support `x25519`? Is there an alternative for x25519 in the WebCrypto API , or is there another way to get this working in Deno?

Comment: No, you'll need an external module and an import map. You can [search for one](https://deno.land/x?query=25519), audit it, and verify that its API is compatible, or write one (and contribute back to Deno's `std` library).

Answer (score 1):

**New answer:** As of Deno 1.33 `generateKeyPairSync` is supported as follows:

```
import { generateKeyPairSync } from "node:crypto";

const keys = generateKeyPairSync("x25519");
```

**Old answer:**

I ended up using an external module as suggested in the comments. I used `node-forge` to generate a keypair:

```
// deno run generate.mjs
import forge from 'npm:node-forge';

const ed25519 = forge.pki.ed25519;

const keypair = ed25519.generateKeyPair();
```

Answer (score 0):

**perhaps this can be possible solution:**

> originally was `window.crypto.subtle.generateKey...` but in case with Deno
> you should (or may) ommit this
> see description bellow

```
const x25519_key = await crypto
  .subtle
  .generateKey({ name: 'X25519' },
    true,
    ['deriveKey', 'deriveBits'],
  );
```

#### below the link with original source of this answer:

#### https://github.com/tQsW/webcrypto-curve25519/blob/master/explainer.md#key-agreement-with-x25519

*P.S. Because Deno is very carefully follows Web API standards (now we can even see his logo in browser-compatibility section on MDN documentation, aka cli-browser)... so you can simply use browser's api without any imports of node's modules etc.*